# Rails - jQuery in form partial works on edit but not on new

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a partial which is rendered using identical code between the new and the edit controller actions, containing a form for the associated model and nested resources.

As a troubleshooting step for working out why the jQuery included in this partial was working on the edit form and not the new form, I've removed all existing jQuery and replaced it with this:

`$("input").click(function() { alert("test!"); });`

This works as expected when loading the edit form, all input fields/buttons/dropdowns display the alert box when clicked. However, when the new form loads, this does not apply.

Any suggestions as to how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: could u pls post more code regarding the issue, any Jquery errors (could obtain via firebug)

Comment: I suspect not relevant, but just in case... you are missing the closing quotes around test! in your code above.

Comment: missing closing quotes were just me typing that out, it is correct in the code itself. Corrected in example above though, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was all caused by an issue with a plugin I was using to help with displaying some of the content; I passed in the string of the div id as an argument to it, and instead of applying its methods directly to the div in the DOM, it duplicated it all further down the page, meaning the id's were being recreated and in addition, meant the jQuery executed on page load didn't apply to the new objects.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might have a javascript error on the new form which is breaking javascript and stopping it from executing further.  Can you use your browser inspector to see if there are any javascript errors on the page?

Comment: Checked with firebug, no errors are reported when loading either form, filling them in, and submitting them.

Comment: If you view page source, is the javascript there?

Comment: So it cant be working in either then.  You need to work out why it isn't there, check they use your layout that includes the javascript if thats how its done.

Comment: It is working in the edit form. But inspecting it in firebug, the script isn't showing up.

Comment: If it works in the edit form, obviously the javascript is there.  You need to find out what you are doing wrong in looking at the code and then compare both forms properly.  Find the code in the edit form, it must be there, and then see if it's in the new form.